# "'Cause girls is players too" grammar

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "'Cause girls is players too" I think 'is' is used instead of 'are'.
Any reason for that and do you know any other examples?

Context: this [lyric](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/coileray/players.html)

Comment: You haven't provided any context here, but it's likely an example of [African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), or perhaps someone trying to imitate AAVE. English language learners should not try to copy this usage and it could be seen as offensive to even try to do so.  Focus on learning standard English.

Comment: It's likely a lyric from the song "players" by Coi Leary.  OP, Remember to link to your sources.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks, the context was added.

Comment: See also the same question on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/603575/girls-is-or-are-from-the-song-players-by-coi-leray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Standard" English (SE), yes, we would use "are" here.

Using "is" with plural subjects is common in [African American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) (AAVE):

> *Is* and *was* are used with plural and second person subjects, e.g., They is crazy, We was there (Wolfram, 1993: 14).
>
> ([quote source](http://events.ff.uni-mb.si/mir/files/2012/EzgetaGrammar.pdf))

Some other dialects of English also do this. Additionally, some SE speakers imitate this type of language for effect (which is especially common in rap).

You can find more examples anywhere that people don't speak SE, including other songs, social media, and the [CORAAL corpus](http://lingtools.uoregon.edu/coraal/explorer/search.php) (in CORAAL, I searched for `(they|people|men|women|\w+[^is]s) is.{15}` but be warned there is profanity).

Note that elsewhere in the song we see another distinctive AAVE verb feature, [copula deletion](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/null-copula), where "is" or "are" is omitted entirely:

> 'Cause when you [] a boss, you could do what you want